# How can I simplify this code instead of repeating it multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textbox

My Problem:

I am using jQuery to capture data from select boxes. Is there a way to simplify the jQuery code instead of repeating it multiple times?

What I am trying to achieve:

I capture the date and name from two select boxes and also the ID of where the final output will be displayed. I pass those values onto a function myfunction. This function will call a php file to connect to a DB and return a certain value and display it onto the text box.

```js
function refreshText() {
  // Row 1
  var name1 = $("#name1").val();
  var date1 = $("#date1").val();
  var textbox = $("#1").attr('id');
  myFunction(date1, name1, textbox)

  var name1 = $("#name1").val();
  var date2 = $("#date2").val();
  var textbox2 = $("#2").attr('id');
  myFunction(date2, name1, textbox2)

  var name1 = $("#name1").val();
  var date3 = $("#date3").val();
  var textbox3 = $("#3").attr('id');
  myFunction(date3, name1, textbox3)

  var name1 = $("#name1").val();
  var date4 = $("#date4").val();
  var textbox4 = $("#4").attr('id');
  myFunction(date4, name1, textbox4)

  var name1 = $("#name1").val();
  var date5 = $("#date5").val();
  var textbox5 = $("#5").attr('id');
  myFunction(date5, name1, textbox5)

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#date1, #date2, #name1, #name2, #name3, #date3, #date4, #date5").change(function() {
      refreshText();
    });
  });

  //Row 2
  var name2 = $("#name2").val();
  var date1 = $("#date1").val();
  var textbox6 = $("#6").attr('id');
  myFunction(date1, name2, textbox6)

  var name2 = $("#name2").val();
  var date2 = $("#date2").val();
  var textbox7 = $("#7").attr('id');
  myFunction(date2, name2, textbox7)

  var name2 = $("#name2").val();
  var date3 = $("#date3").val();
  var textbox8 = $("#8").attr('id');
  myFunction(date3, name2, textbox8)

  var name2 = $("#name2").val();
  var date4 = $("#date4").val();
  var textbox9 = $("#9").attr('id');
  myFunction(date4, name2, textbox9)

  var name2 = $("#name2").val();
  var date5 = $("#date5").val();
  var textbox10 = $("#10").attr('id');
  myFunction(date5, name2, textbox10)

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><select id="date1"><option value="Select">Select</option></select></td>
    <td><select id="date2"><option value="Select">Select</option></select></td>
    <td><select id="date3"><option value="Select">Select</option></select></td>
    <td><select id="date4"><option value="Select">Select</option></select></td>
    <td><select id="date5"><option value="Select">Select</option></select></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><select id="name1" class="allNames"><option value="Select">Select</option><option value="alex">alex</option><option value="daniel">daniel</option><option value="Joe">Joe</option>
     </select></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="1" readonly="readonly"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="2" readonly="readonly"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="3" readonly="readonly"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="4" readonly="readonly"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="5" readonly="readonly"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><select id="name2" class="allNames"><option value="Select">Select</option><option value="Joe">Joe</option><option value="alex">alex</option><option value="daniel">daniel</option>
     </select></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="6" readonly="readonly"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="7" readonly="readonly"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="8" readonly="readonly"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="9" readonly="readonly"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="10" readonly="readonly"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: A lot of your code doesn't make sense. All your select boxes only have one option. Your change handler wont ever trigger because there are no options to change to.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

create a function called `updateData`

```
function updateData(nameInput, dateInput, tbInput)
{ 
    var name = $(nameInput).val();
    var date = $(dateInput).val();
    var textbox = $(tbInput).attr('id');

    myFunction(date,name,textbox) ;
}
```

and then in your `refreshText` just call it like this

```
function refreshText(){
   updateData("#name1","#date1","#1")
   updateData("#name1","#date2","#2")
   ....
}
```

By the way this line looks a little bit weird

```
 var textbox = $("#1").attr('id');
```

since variable `textbox` will be assigned with "1" since you are looking up the control using the ID to obtain the ID

Answer (score 0):

Check this. What I have done is I just gave dropdown attribute either `row` or `col`(if they refer column than give `col` otherwise `row`). Now when user select any of this dropdown based on the dropdown(name or date) get value of require and call the function. (if you see the function you will get better understanding)(I didn't call function for some because changing value of dropdown will not their value)

```js
var row=2,col=5;
$("#date1, #date2, #name1, #name2, #name3, #date3, #date4, #date5").change(function () {
    refreshText(this);
});

function myFunction(a,b,c){console.log(a+' '+b+' '+c);};
function refreshText(e){
          if($(e).attr('col')){
              var date=$(e).val();
              for(i = 1 ; i <= row ; i++){
                  var name=$("#name"+i).val();
                  var textboxId='#'+ +$(e).attr('col') * + $("#name"+i).attr('row');
                  var textbox=$(textbox1Id).val();
                  myFunction(date, name, textbox)
              }
          }
          else{
              var name=$(e).val();
              for(i = 1 ; i <= col ; i++){
                  var date = $('#date'+i).val();
                  var textboxId = '#'+ +$(e).attr('row') * + $("#date"+i).attr('col');
                  var textbox=$(textboxId).val();
                  myFunction(date, name, textbox);
              }
          
          }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><select id="date1" col="1"><option value="Select">Select</option></select></td>
    <td><select id="date2" col="2"><option value="Select">Select</option></select></td>
    <td><select id="date3" col="3"><option value="Select">Select</option></select></td>
    <td><select id="date4" col="4"><option value="Select">Select</option></select></td>
    <td><select id="date5" col="5"><option value="Select">Select</option></select></td>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td><select id="name1" class="allNames" row="1"><option value="Select">Select</option><option value="alex">alex</option><option value="daniel">daniel</option><option value="Joe">Joe</option>
    </select></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="1" col="1" row="1" readonly="readonly" ></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="2" col="2" row="1" readonly="readonly" ></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="3" col="3" row="1" readonly="readonly" ></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="4" col="4" row="1" readonly="readonly" ></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="5" col="5" row="1" readonly="readonly" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><select id="name2" class="allNames" row="2"><option value="Select">Select</option><option value="Joe">Joe</option><option value="alex">alex</option><option value="daniel">daniel</option>
    </select></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="6" col="1" row="2" readonly="readonly" value="10"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="7" col="2" row="2" readonly="readonly" ></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="8" col="3" row="2" readonly="readonly" ></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="9" col="4" row="2" readonly="readonly" ></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="10" col="5" row="2" readonly="readonly" ></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Select boxes for date with only one option will not trigger the change event.

To loop through names and dates you can try below function (assuming you have five dates and 10 input text boxes as shown in your code snippet

```
function regreshText(){
    var var_all_names = $('#myTable td').children('select.allNames');
    for(i = 0; i < var_all_names.length; i++){
        for(j = 1; j <= 5; j++){
            if(var_all_names[i].id == 'name1'){
                myFunction($('#date'+j), var_all_names[i], $('#textbox'+j));
            }
            if(var_all_names[i].id == 'name2'){
                myFunction($('#date'+j), var_all_names[i], $('#textbox'+ parseInt(j+5)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below solution

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#date1, #date2, #name1, #name2, #name3, #date3, #date4, #date5").change(function() {
    console.clear();
    refreshText();
  });
});

function refreshText() {
  $("#myTable").find("input[type=text]").each(function(i, element)    {
    var nameId = "name1";
    var dateId = "date" + (i + 1);
    if (i > 4) {
      nameId = "name2";
      dateId = "date" + (i - 4)
    }

    var nameVal = $("#" + nameId).val();
    var dateVal = $("#" + dateId).val()
    var textId = $("#" + (i+1)).attr('id');
    myFunction(nameVal, dateVal, textId)

   //for test
    $(element).val($("#" + dateId).val() + " / " +
      $("#" + nameId).val())
  });
}

function myFunction(nameVal, dateVal,textId) {
  console.log("name value: " + nameVal + " | date value: " + dateVal + " | text id: " + textId);
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <table id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><select id="date1"><option value="Select">Select</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      </select></td>
      <td><select id="date2"><option value="Select">Select</option>
      <option value="2">2</option></select></td>
      <td><select id="date3"><option value="Select">Select</option>
      <option value="3">3</option></select></td>
      <td><select id="date4"><option value="Select">Select</option>
      <option value="4">4</option></select></td>
      <td><select id="date5"><option value="Select">Select</option>
      <option value="5">5</option></select></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select id="name1" class="allNames">
                    <option value="Select">Select</option>
                    <option value="alex">alex</option>
                    <option value="daniel">daniel</option>
                    <option value="Joe">Joe</option>
                </select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" id="1" readonly="readonly"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="2" readonly="readonly"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="3" readonly="readonly"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="4" readonly="readonly"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="5" readonly="readonly"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select id="name2" class="allNames">
                    <option value="Select">Select</option>
                    <option value="Joe">Joe</option>
                    <option value="alex">alex</option>
                    <option value="daniel">daniel</option>
                </select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" id="6" readonly="readonly"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="7" readonly="readonly"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="8" readonly="readonly"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="9" readonly="readonly"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="10" readonly="readonly"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```